# Magento: Catalog > Manage Products page is blank (rest of the backend is working fine)

Tags: php, magento

Yesterday we have imported a csv of 1.5 million products into magento using MAGMI extension.

Suddenly in the backend 'Catalog > Manage Products' page is blank. There are no errors, i have enabled error logging, exception printing, php error reporting, restarted apache server.

Note:

- All the other pages in backend are working fine.
- The products are imported properly (we are able to verify using search, also in category management the products are assigned to the categories)
- Other errors are getting logged (verified using Mage:log() )

How do i identify and solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused because of the memory limits set by php & magento..

we had to increase the memory_limit in the php.ini file, and importantly we also had to do the same in .htaccess file in the magento root.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check for any newly extension installed that have control over admin grid (May be some attribute data required by the extension may be skipped during importing process)
2. Check in Apache error.log,mysql.log .(There would always be a trace)
3. If anything isn't working override admin controllers for product and identify the               function causing the issue.

> Note: Please share the log generated details from magento .

Comment: hey buddy, thanks for the answer, somehow the logs were not being udpated, we fixed it and could get the logs working fine, and then we could identify the problem..